# LibGDX - Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Tags: android, libgdx, dalvik

I know this question has been asked hundreds of times, but there's a consistency to them - recently updated packages. I haven't updated anything in weeks, and the problem suddenly occured after I corrected a simpleton spelling mistake. I can't get the stack trace because I get this infinitely at an instantaneous pace: `"sensor_work - read value = ###"` where ### can be 290 to 320.

Note - I'm using LibGDX, so checking libraries was difficult and took a decent amount of time. There are six. I may have missed something but I'm 99% sure I didn't.
I've tried:

- Building and cleaning, or vice versa
- Moving contents to new packages
- Sorting through libraries for duplicates/old versions
- Recovering previous project build (from yesterday)

Any insight towards the problem would be appreciated, and please, don't just link me to a duplicate question - trust me, I've probably already read it.

Comment: What exactly did you change? How are you building/running your app?

Comment: A strong being output in the console. Eclipse.

Comment: Eclipse via the gradle plugin? Have you tried it from the commandline?

Comment: Yes. No, where can I find that?

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-on-the-Commandline

Comment: Okay, now where I'm confused is where to actually run those. Can't seem to find anything useful.

Comment: Uuummm... on the commandline? From your project root folder.

Comment: Well, yeah, but everything I can find says to go to Arguments in either run or debug settings. I don't have that in any of my projects - core, Android, Desktop, etc.

Comment: The Gradle commands from the Windows CMD seem to be checking the wrong workspace - Eclipse's default, whereas my LibGDX projects have a separate folder (they put themselves there and trying to move them broke things). Any way I can fix that?